# Какая редакция предложения правильная?

Tags: пунктуация

1. Мое мнение — рынок диктует свои условия, и спрос на запорную арматуру как был, так и останется: никто не отменял текущие и капитальные ремонты теплосетей, ввод нового жилья, строительство новых газопроводов и других объектов.
2. Мое мнение: рынок диктует свои условия, и спрос на запорную арматуру как был, так и останется — никто не отменял текущие и капитальные ремонты теплосетей, ввод нового жилья, строительство новых газопроводов и других объектов.

Answer (score 3):

Возможны обе редакции, но я бы выбрал вторую, поскольку двоеточие нужнее перед раскрытием содержания мнения, а дважды его в этом предложении не получится употребить. Этот вариант нейтрален, в то время как первый вариант имеет почти вызывающий оттенок: через тире личное мнение как бы противопоставляется всем прочим, включая ещё не высказанные.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы во втором варианте тире заменил на "***, ибо***"

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта возможны, но они предполагают **разные смысловые оттенки и разную интонацию.**

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Предложение написано в стиле публицистики: идет обсуждение проблемы, люди высказывают свои мнения. **Грамматика публицистической речи более разнообразна**, ведь задача говорящего - это воздействовать на своего оппонента, на его мысли, чувства.

2) Живую ткань такой речи достаточно трудно передать на письме, поэтому в публицистике (и в художественных произведениях) **трудно следовать классическим, жестким, формальным правилам.**

3) В нашем случае мы хотим передать **два вида интонации**.

а) В первом случае (ставим тире) говорящий делает логическое ударение на "мое мнение", противопоставляя его мнению других. Смысл такой - **"что касается моего мнения, то...".**

"Мое мнение — рынок диктует свои условия, и спрос на запорную арматуру как был, так и останется: никто не отменял текущие и капитальные ремонты теплосетей, ввод нового жилья, строительство новых газопроводов и других объектов". **Повышение тона** перед паузой, обозначенной тире.

б) Во втором случае (ставим двоеточие) он **раскрывает содержание своего мнения**. И здесь смысловое значение немного меняется: "мое мнение таково".

"Моё мнение: рынок диктует свои условия, и спрос на запорную арматуру как был, так и останется - никто не отменял текущие и капитальные ремонты теплосетей, ввод нового жилья, строительство новых газопроводов и других объектов". **Понижение тона** перед значительно увеличенной паузой, обозначено двоеточием.

4) Но **для окончательного решения нужно видеть весь текст**, так как предложение должно соответствовать его общей грамматике и стилю.

Comment: Вопрос не о "нравится/не", а о 1. корректном 2. русском 3. письменном тексте. В таком ашпекте рекомендовать версию 1 - солженицынщина

Comment: Сударыня, избавьте меня от вашего совершенно необоснованного агро. И "Справочник" 2008-2009 года **для меня** - не авторитет *ни разу*. Хайль Розенталь! К Паустовскому претензий не имею - он "такъ видитъ", а правила говорят "как положено"

Answer (score 0):

Единственно правильным является второй вариант безальтернативно ("авторская пунктуация" - отмазка неграмотных бездарей):

- Двоеточие разделяет утверждение и его раскрытие
- Тире, как и положено, используется на месте *пропущенного текста*, неважно что читающий видит в пропуске: "ибо/так как/потому что"